Which kind of matching can i use and why doesnt my propensity score matching work?
I am currently trying to find out if a certain disease characteristic affects long term survival. I have observational data and i am trying to match my cohort, as there are huge baseline differences between the two groups. I have tried propensity score matching, which yield very poor results, it increases balance a little bit, but not by much. I have about 6 variables id like to match on, which are relevant for long term survival. I am using the matchit() package on R. Here is my code used for matching:
 m.data <- matchit(mydata$cto ~ X, data = mydata, method = "optimal", distance = "glm", estimand = "ATC") X is a list of my covariables. This is the permutation of parameters which yields the most balanced dataset. But there are still significant baseline differences which id like to get rid of. How would you go about archieving a better match.
PS: I know of the pitfalls of propensity score matching. I am not trying to proof causation here, i simply want my data to give me a direction for future work.

It's not clear why matching is a good idea in this setting.  Also, most matching algorithms discard data or are processing-order-dependent, both very problematic.

My first bit of advice would be to try other matching methods. You are trying optimal matching, but you could try nearest or full and see if your results improve. You can also try exact matching, where you specify the variables on which you want to match exactly, which is done with an argument like exact = ~ X1 + X2.
You could also try using distance = "mahalanobis" instead of the glm argument and see if that helps.
Otherwise, if these coding methods don't work, my next suggestion is to consider dropping a variable or two from your model. You don't have a ton of variables to start with, but just one problematic variable can cause matching problems for the entire matching algorithm. I would look for highly skewed or disproportionate variables here. If you've got a variable where 95%+ of it is at one level and the other 5% is at another, or spread amongst a variety of other levels, that one would mess up a matching algorithm for sure. Ideally, your variables have an evenly diverse spread of data for matching to work best.
